# How to install Juniper.junos ansible-galaxy in mac?

Tags: automation, ansible, ansible-galaxy, juniper, pyez

I tried to install the latest version of Juniper.junos on my Mac :

```
sudo ansible-galaxy install Juniper.junos

   -downloading role 'junos', owned by Juniper

   -downloading role from https://github.com/Juniper/ansible-junos-stdlib/archive/2.0.2.tar.gz

[ERROR]: failed to download the file: Failed to validate the SSL certificate for github.com:443. Make sure your managedsystems have a valid CA certificate installed. You can use validate_certs=False if you do not need to confirm the servers identity but this is unsafe and not recommended. Paths checked for this platform: /etc/ssl/certs, /etc/ansible, /usr/local/etc/openssl. The exception msg was: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590).

[WARNING]: - Juniper.junos was NOT installed successfully.

ERROR! - you can use --ignore-errors to skip failed roles and finish processing the list.
```

ansible-galaxy --version
ansible-galaxy 2.5.0

I already tried with different ansible versions, but the error is still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are facing this issue sometimes, it’s connectivity issue to install module via ansible-galaxy, not related to Juniper ansible module.

Kindly use below command for installation, it will work well.

```
sudo ansible-galaxy install git+https://github.com/Juniper/ansible junos-stdlib.git,,Juniper.junos

[abc@hostname /homes/abc] sudo ansible-galaxy install git+https://github.com/Juniper/ansible-junos-stdlib.git,,Juniper.junos

- extracting Juniper.junos to /homes/babud/.ansible/roles/Juniper.junos
- Juniper.junos was installed successfully
```